# Using Firebase Web Framework (Beta) with Next.js and Prisma?

Tags: next.js, prisma, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I'm building an [app](https://github.com/RMHAM/open-ics) with Next.js which uses server side rendering (SSR) and Prisma to read from a database. This is working well locally.

I'm trying to host on Firebase Hosting, and I'm attempting to use the [beta feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs) which detects web frameworks in the source instead of having to pre-build everything. The static parts of the site predictably work, but anything that tries to use SSR to invoke Prisma fails with a 500. When I look at the Cloud Functions logs, I find `Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.`

I suspect the Firebase web frameworks feature does not yet support non-standard build steps like generating the Prisma client. Does anyone know for sure if that's the case, or if the Firebase build process can be customized to include `npx prisma generate`?

Comment: Is `npx prisma generate` a part of your build script?

Comment: As in the `package.json` build script? It [isn't yet](https://github.com/RMHAM/open-ics/blob/e247a9cb56ac6fe91786d72055f8d41082d98a8c/package.json#L7) but I can try to add it...

Comment: Great suggestion, but that didn't help. After re-deploying with [that change](https://github.com/RMHAM/open-ics/commit/9c66d324d9f6777d4c8a2bedf0eb62602d745985), my Cloud Function is failing with the same error message.

Comment: Ah Okay, Let me further investigate and check if I can find a solution.

Comment: @NurulSundarani, I'm working around the issue by switching from Postgres to MongoDB, and Prisma to Mongoose. NextJS and Mongoose seems to be working with Firebase Hosting's web framework beta. 

However, I will preserve the [prisma branch](https://github.com/RMHAM/open-ics/tree/prisma) of my project if you want to continue experimenting.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Altough I added npx prisma generate to postinstall / build and even in the firebase.json under "predeploy"
Nothing worked.